# Mysql - sql query to get next class based on date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in my webinar_timing table in mysql database

start_time and end_time are of type datetime

```
   id  | webinar_id | start_time            | end_time
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  |     5      | 3/18/2015  6:00:00 PM | 3/18/2015  7:00:00 PM
    2  |     5      | 3/19/2015  6:00:00 PM | 3/19/2015  7:00:00 PM
    3  |     5      | 3/20/2015  6:00:00 PM | 3/20/2015  7:00:00 PM
    4  |     5      | 3/21/2015  6:00:00 PM | 3/21/2015  7:00:00 PM
    5  |     5      | 3/22/2015  6:00:00 PM | 3/22/2015  7:00:00 PM
    6  |    11      | 3/20/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/20/2015  9:00:00 PM
    7  |    11      | 3/21/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/21/2015  9:00:00 PM
    8  |    11      | 3/22/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/22/2015  9:00:00 PM
    9  |    22      | 3/25/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/25/2015  9:00:00 PM
   10  |    22      | 3/27/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/27/2015  9:00:00 PM
   11  |    22      | 3/29/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/27/2015  9:00:00 PM
```

Basically, for each webinar, I want the total occurences and number of classes completed or remaining AND the NEXT upcoming class

Egs: When I run this query say at 3/21/2015 at 4:00 PM - this is the result I am expecting

```
 webinar_id | total     | Classes Completed | Next Class
----------------------------------------------------------
     5      |   5       | 3                 | 3/21/2015  6:00:00 PM
    11      |   3       | 1                 | 3/21/2015  8:00:00 PM
    22      |   3       | 0                 | 3/25/2015  8:00:00 PM
```

OR

```
 webinar_id | total     | Classes Remaining | Next Class
----------------------------------------------------------
     5      |   5       | 2                 | 3/21/2015  6:00:00 PM
    11      |   3       | 2                 | 3/21/2015  8:00:00 PM
    22      |   3       | 3                 | 3/25/2015  8:00:00 PM
```

Based on a previous question - a fellow SO Peter assisted with the following

```
select webinar_id, count(*) AS total, 
SUM(IF(end_time<NOW(), 1, 0)) AS completed, 
SUM(IF(start_time>=NOW(), 1, 0)) AS remaining
from webinar_times
group by webinar_id;
```

SQL Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4e71/1

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide sample data as insert statements or create an sqlfiddle?

Comment: Hi Lennart - I have added the sqlfiddle - basically need to add the next class date to the result - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
select webinar_id
     , count(*) AS total
     , count(case when end_time<NOW() then 1 end) as completed
     , (select count(1) 
        from webinar_times y
        where x.webinar_id = y.webinar_id
          and y.start_time > NOW()) as remaining
     , min(case when x.start_time > NOW() then x.start_time end) as next_class
from webinar_times x
group by webinar_id;
```

should do

EDIT: realized that the sub-select is un-necessary:

```
select webinar_id
     , count(*) AS total
     , count(case when end_time<NOW() then 1 end) as completed
     , count(case when start_time>NOW() then 1 end) as remaining  
     , min(case when x.start_time > NOW() then x.start_time end) as next_class     
from webinar_times x
group by webinar_id;
```

Comment: Hi Lennart - this does not get the next upcoming class in the result - thanks

Comment: FWIW, you don't need the sub-select. I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an outer join between two grouped queries, e.g. one that counts the total number of webinars and another that both counts the remaining webinars and obtains the start time of the next one:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT   webinar_id, COUNT(*) total
    FROM     webinar_times
    GROUP BY webinar_id
) totals NATURAL LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT   webinar_id, COUNT(*) remaining, MIN(start_time) next
    FROM     webinar_times
    WHERE    start_time > NOW()
    GROUP BY webinar_id
) future
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4e71/12/0):

```
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------+
| webinar_id | total | remaining |                    next |
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------+
|          6 |     5 |         1 | March, 22 2015 06:00:00 |
|         11 |     3 |         1 | March, 22 2015 07:00:00 |
|         22 |     3 |         3 | March, 25 2015 07:00:00 |
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

A composite index defined over `(webinar_id, start_time)` would benefit this query, and avoids the full table scans that the approach outlined in your question would otherwise require.

Comment: Got it - will look into creating the composite index - In this query - is it possible to get completed classes as well along with remaining classes

Comment: @Gublooo: One could just add `total - remaining AS completed` to the (outermost) `SELECT` list (or do it within the data access layer).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example and this will give you what you need

```
mysql> create table test (id int, webinar_id int, start_time datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (1,5,'2015-03-18 18:00:00'),
  (2,5,'2015-03-19 18:00:00'),
  (3,5,'2015-03-20 18:00:00'),
  (4,5,'2015-03-21 18:00:00'),
  (5,5,'2015-03-21 18:00:00'),
  (6,11,'2015-03-20 20:00:00'),
  (7,11,'2015-03-21 20:00:00'),
  (8,11,'2015-03-22 20:00:00'),
  (9,22,'2015-03-25 20:00:00'),
  (10,22,'2015-03-27 20:00:00'),
  (11,22,'2015-03-29 20:00:00');
Query OK, 11 rows affected (0.05 sec)

Records: 11  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test ;
+------+------------+---------------------+
| id   | webinar_id | start_time          |
+------+------------+---------------------+
|    1 |          5 | 2015-03-18 18:00:00 |
|    2 |          5 | 2015-03-19 18:00:00 |
|    3 |          5 | 2015-03-20 18:00:00 |
|    4 |          5 | 2015-03-21 18:00:00 |
|    5 |          5 | 2015-03-21 18:00:00 |
|    6 |         11 | 2015-03-20 20:00:00 |
|    7 |         11 | 2015-03-21 20:00:00 |
|    8 |         11 | 2015-03-22 20:00:00 |
|    9 |         22 | 2015-03-25 20:00:00 |
|   10 |         22 | 2015-03-27 20:00:00 |
|   11 |         22 | 2015-03-29 20:00:00 |
+------+------------+---------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select 
t.webinar_id, 
count(*) as total,
sum( case when t.start_time < now() then 1 else 0 end) as completed , 
sum( case when t.start_time > now() then 1 else 0 end) as remaining,
t1.next_date from test t 
join ( 
  select 
  webinar_id,
  min(start_time) as next_date 
  from test where start_time > now() 
  group by webinar_id 
)t1 on t.webinar_id= t1.webinar_id 
group by t.webinar_id;

+------------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| webinar_id | total | completed | remaining | next_date           |
+------------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
|          5 |     5 |         3 |         2 | 2015-03-21 18:00:00 |
|         11 |     3 |         1 |         2 | 2015-03-21 20:00:00 |
|         22 |     3 |         0 |         3 | 2015-03-25 20:00:00 |
+------------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You probably want that to be an outer join, so that any webinars for which there are no remaining classes do not get entirely removed from the resultset.

Comment: Thanks Abhik - this looks similar to the approach suggested by eggyal - let me study this a bit - thanks much

Comment: @eggyal correct left outer join would be needed than inner join to fulfill that condition.